# NSubstitute Mocking new T property

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I try to create a mock for an existing interface. When I try to read the value, I get a **null reference exception**

```
    public interface MyInterface<T> : MyInterface
    {
        new T Value { get; set; }
    }

    public interface MyInterface : MyReadonlyInterface
    {
        new object Value { get; set; }
    }

    public interface MyReadonlyInterface
    {
        object Value { get; }
    }
...
    var i = Substitute.For<MyInterface<bool>>();
    variable.Value = false;
```

Just after inititialize I see the value as "false". Later in the test, the value will become NULL. The usualy used

```
variable.Value.Returns(false)
```

also shows NULL.
How do I have to use NSubstitute to get the required "false" without changing the interface?

Comment: Don't you have to implicitly cast to `MyInterface<T>` to access the `new` property?

Comment: Your code does not make sense to me. If you create a mock you need to set the value using Returns. So i.Value.Returns(false) should work as expected. You access variable.Value. From the snipped it is completely unclear what you expect

Comment: Thanks to @orhtej2. Your question led me to the solution. Playing aroud, I finally found that `variable.Value.Returns(x=> false);` always returns the required bool value instead of NULL the second time it's read.